# When casting Infestation as an opportunity attack with the War Caster feat, how does the forced movement affect the targets turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack, cantrips, forced-movement

With the War Caster feat, you are allowed to cast a spell as a reaction when a target provokes an opportunity attack. The [infestation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/infestation) cantrip states that the creature

> moves 5 feet in a random direction if it can move and its speed is at
> least 5 feet.

Does that creature then end its turn, or does the creature simply move 5 in a random direction and then continues its turn as normal?

The description also states:

> if the direction rolled is blocked, the target doesn’t move.

Does this mean that in this specific scenario the target loses its movement, or is it simply referring to the 5 feet forced by the spell itself?

Comment: Related: "[Does someone who fails against Dissonant Whispers on their turn waste their movement for that turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135287)"

Answer (score 2):

#### Being unable to move only prevents moving those 5 feet

The [*infestation*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/infestation) cantrip states:

> [...] The target must succeed on a Constitution saving throw, or it takes 1d6 poison damage and moves 5 feet in a random direction if it can move and its speed is at least 5 feet. Roll a d4 for the direction: 1, north; 2, south; 3, east; or 4, west. This movement doesn't provoke opportunity attacks, and if the direction rolled is blocked, the target doesn't move. [...]

If the rolled direction is blocked, the target doesn't move. This means the target doesn't move *those 5 feet*. If it somehow prevented them from moving at all, it would state as much, and if we *do* interpret this as preventing them from moving then no duration is listed and the creature could never move ever again.

---

#### Whose turn it is does *not* change

Nothing in the spell's description claims that moving (or failing to move) would end the creature's turn. You are simply forcing them to take some damage and move in a random direction, nothing else. The target's turn continues as normal after the spell is cast because no part of the spell states anything to the contrary.

---

#### The cantrip *might* use up 5 feet of the target's movement

This is a bit of a sidenote bug when this spell occurs on the target creature's turn, they would be forced to move 5 feet in a random direction. Notably, this movement is not using up their reaction or any other part of their action economy. Except, one could argue that this movement actually uses up their movement as it makes them move on their turn. One could also argue that it does not use up their movement, the same way it doesn't use their movement when it *isn't* their turn. This is a rather unclear section of the rules and the following question has answers arguing about a similar spell where you can see a few different trains of logic:

- [Does someone who fails against Dissonant Whispers on their turn waste their movement for that turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135287)